# How would I use the cursor.map function to skip one of the the first item in a collection

Tags: javascript, dictionary, meteor, skip

I have the following template helper for outputting the first {{url}} and all the {{thumb}}
however I want to skip the first item if the {{thumb}} not sure how to do this in the map function.

```
Template.motionPictures.helpers({
  posts: function() {

  return  Posts.find({}, {fields: {thumb: 1, url: 1}}).map(function(post, index) {
  if (index === 0) {
    return post;
  } else {
    delete post.url;
    return post;
  }
});

}
});
```

When I console.log the posts array, I get the following

[image]

This is what I expected but I want the first object in the array to only show its {{url}} not is {{thumb}} so far all the suggestions just delete the object in total, or not at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you both had good advice but I didn't realize what I had to do until I did that console .log.

The following code worked just as I wanted it to

```
Template.motionPictures.helpers({
  posts: function() {
   return Posts
        .find({}, {fields: {thumb: 1, url: 1}, sort: {createdAt: -1}})
        .map(function(post, index) {
          if (index === 0) {

            delete post.thumb;
            return post;


          } else {
            delete post.url;
            return post;
          }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Yep, that looks right. I just didn't fully understand what you needed until I saw your last comment.

Comment: No Worries, Id rather choose your answer, but I don't know whats best practice, to choose the one I was looking for or the one that helped me figure it out.

Comment: If you have the reputation to do so, I think you should accept your own answer. If you can't, then I can modify mine.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `skip`:

```
Posts.find({}, {fields: {thumb: 1, url: 1}, skip: 1})..map(fun...
```

Comment: I tried that, but I dont want to skip the first {{url}} only the skip the first {{thumb}}

Comment: I'm not exactly sure by what you mean by this. If you rephrase it to something more concise I could be of more help

Comment: When I use the skip option, it skips both the thumb and the urls first item in the database, I want the first item of the url to show but the first item of the thumb not to be outputted.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you just want to remove the 2nd item of the posts array prior to returning from the helper function. To do this, you can just assign the result of the `map` to a variable and then call [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) on it. Give this a try:

```
Template.motionPictures.helpers({
  posts: function() {
    var posts =
      Posts
        .find({}, {fields: {thumb: 1, url: 1}})
        .map(function(post, index) {
          if (index === 0) {
            return post;
          } else {
            delete post.url;
            return post;
          }
        });

    posts.splice(1, 1);
    return posts;
  }
});
```

Comment: Its so close, but it deletes the last {{thumb}} image and not the the first one. I tried modifying it to posts.splice(0,1); which worked but also got rid of the the {{url}} first one.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this code removes the second item in the `posts` array. I suspect the problem is that the posts need to be sorted in a way that hasn't been specified. If, for example, you want to order them by their creation date then you could do something like: `find({}, {fields: {thumb: 1, url: 1}, sort: {createdAt: -1}})`.

Comment: I added a console.log of my posts variable the array is of 3 objects and I want the first object to remove its thumb value and keep the url. Not delete the whole first object, I added a image above.